# Python: remove white spaces in dictionary return 'list' object has no attribute 'rstrip'

Tags: python, dictionary, strip

I have a dictionary which has whitespaces in the beginning and end of the items that I want to remove.

```
Alpha = {'Active': [{'Last': u' 0.023', 'Name': u' Bard1 Life Sciences Limited                                       


                ', 'Vol': u' 439,937,304', 'pc': u' 130.0', 'Change': u' 0.013', 'Stock': 'BD1'}, {'Last': u'
 0.048', 'Name': u' Patrys Ltd                                                                               

                                                                                                      ', 'Vol
': u' 60,198,817', 'pc': u' -9.4', 'Change': u' -0.005', 'Stock': 'PAB'}, {'Last': u' 0.008', 'Name': u' Ecli
pse Metals Limited.                                                                                          

                                                                              ', 'Vol': u' 41,707,516', 'pc':
 u' -33.3', 'Change': u' -0.004', 'Stock': 'EPM'}]}
```

I want to remove white spaces for Name at the end, and remove the white spaces at the beginning for Last,Change and pc.

When I use `{key: value.rstrip() for key, value in Alpha.items()}`, it return `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rstrip'`. It is the same when I use `lstrip` as well.

What is the pythonic way to solve the error?

Comment: Your value is a `list` and does not have the `rstrip` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before solving this, you have to become aware of your structure: you don't have a dictionary with whitespaces in the beginning, but a dictionary string → list of dictionaries of whose values are some with strings having whitespace around it.

That sounds complicated, and it is (a little bit). But that's why your approach doesn't work.

I would do it recursively:

```
def my_strip(item):
    if isinstance(item, str) or isinstance(item, unicode):
        return item.rstrip()
    if isinstance(item, list):
        return [my_strip(i) for i in item]
    if isinstance(item, dict):
        return {k: my_strip(v) for k, v in item.items()}
    return item
```

This way, all your levels are appropriately treated if you just do

Answer (score 1):

You missed the List inside the `Alpha['Active']`.

The data is maintained in the following manner:

```
Alpha = dict(key: list[ dict(key, value), dict(key, value), dict(key, value)])
```

We want to remove the left and right spaces for the actual values inside the list.

You can use:

```
for index, itemdict in enumerate(Alpha['Active']):
    Alpha['Active'][index] = {key: value.strip() for key, value in itemdict.items()}
```

And at the end you can see your data without the spaces using:

```
# to print the data
for item in Alpha['Active']:
    print(item)
```

Result:

```
{'Last': '0.023', 'Name': 'Bard1 Life Sciences Limited', 'Vol': '439,937,304', 'pc': '130.0', 'Change': '0.013', 'Stock': 'BD1'}
{'Last': '0.048', 'Name': 'Patrys Ltd', 'Vol': '60,198,817', 'pc': '-9.4', 'Change': '-0.005', 'Stock': 'PAB'}
{'Last': '0.008', 'Name': 'Ecli\npse Metals Limited.', 'Vol': '41,707,516', 'pc': '-33.3', 'Change': '-0.004', 'Stock': 'EPM'}
```